# Add to page title tag based on variable from URL

Tags: php, url, variables, tags, title

I have seen the following thread but it's a bit beyond me...

[How can I change the <title> tag dynamically in php based on the URL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441565/how-can-i-change-the-title-tag-dynamically-in-php-based-on-the-url-values)

Basically, I have a page index.php (no php in it just named to future proof - maybe now!). It contains numerous lightbox style galleries which can be triggered from an external link by a variable in the URL - e.g. index.php?open=true2, index.php?open=true3, etc.

I would like the index.php title tag - to include existing static data + append additional words based on the URL variable - e.g. if URL open=true2 add "car gallery", if URL open=true3 add "cat gallery", if URL has no variable append nothing to title.

Can anyone assist? I have been searching but either missed the point of posts or it hasn't been covered (to my amateaur level).

Many thanks. Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your php script put this:

```
<?php

# define your titles
$titles = array('true2' => 'Car Gallery', 'true3' => 'Cat Gallery');

# if the 'open' var is set then get the appropriate title from the $titles array
# otherwise set to empty string.
$title = (isset($_GET['open']) ? ' - '.$titles[$_GET['open']] : '');

?>
```

And then use this to include your custom title:

`<title>Pauls Great Site<?php echo htmlentities($title); ?></title>`

Comment: I've tested this one very quickly because it includes the ability to convert the URL variable to something more appropriate for the title. Works a treat in Firefox. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments / help. I will keep an eye on this thread - re any ongoing potential attack issues especially.

Comment: Glad we could help Paul. @Treffynnon thanks for adding the htmlentities(). Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>Your Static Stuff <?php echo $your_dyamic_stuff;?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if( array_key_exists('open', $_GET) ){
        $title = $_GET['open'];
    }else{
        $title = '';
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_title.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP can fetch information from the URL querystring (www.yoursite.com?page=1&cat=dog etc). You need to fetch that information, make sure it's not malicious, and then you could insert it into the title. Here's a simple example - for your application, make sure you sanitise the data and check it isn't malicious:

```
<?php
$open = "";

// check querystring exists
if (isset($_GET['open'])) {
// if it does, assign it to variable
$open = $_GET['open'];
}
?>

<html><head><title>This is the title: <?php $open ?></title></head>
```

PHP has lots of functions for escaping data that might contain nasty stuff - if you look up htmlspecialchars and htmlentities you should find information that will help.

Comment: Yes it is however it is still important to caveat it.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers are open to abuse try this instead:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('open', $_GET)){
        $title = $_GET['open'];
    } else {
        $title = '';
    }
    $title = strip_tags($title);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>The content of the document......</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise as @Ben has mentioned. Define you titles in your PHP first to prevent people from being able to directly inject text into your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for adding the essential detail of your answer - `echo htmlentities(..)` to the accepted answer.